# Insert into multiple tables doesn't insert all records

Tags: php, mysql, insert, multiple-tables

I am new to PHP and MySQL. I am facing a problem: some records are inserted into the database, and some records are not inserted. There are two tables

1. Login
2. Profile

No problem with the Login table, it always inserts records. But there is a problem with the profile table. Some records have been inserted but some not.

My database is on live. Many people fill forms so I observe no record second table. Here is code:

```
$pwd= $_POST['spwd'];(Get all values in the form of post)

$a1 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO Login (email,password,active) VALUES('$email','$pwd','1')");
$fk=mysql_insert_id();
if($fk!=0)
{
$a2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO Profile (name,father,age,gender,kids,nationality,house,height,whenmarry,description,partnerquality,imagepath,email,mobile,mstatus,cast,education,religion,aqeeda,peer,madaniwork,country,city,zip,job,familydetail,salary,bodybuilt,fklogin) 
                   VALUES('$name','$father',$age,$gender,$kids,'$nationality','$house','$height',$whenmarry,'$description','$partnerquality','$new_image_name','$email','$mobile',$ms,'$mothertongue','$education',$religion,$aqeeda,'$peer',$mwork,$country,'$city','$zip','$sjob','$fd','$salary',$bbuilt,$fk)");

}
if ($a1 and $a2) {

 $response["success"] = 1;
 $response["message"] = "Register Successfully";
 echo json_encode($response);

}
```

Comment: I bet if you echo out the full SQL of `INSERT INTO Profile (name,father,age,gender,kids,nationality....` you would find an empty/typo'ed variable in there. Or you are trying to insert a string into a text field (no quotes around gender, religion, aqeeda, mwork, country for example).

Comment: gender, religion, aqeeda, mwork, country this is not string but integer.Even total record i found in database 50 but 10 records are missing from second table..why 40 records inserted only?there is no empty variables..except zip contact peer these values can null

Comment: Never ever do this!!! First, `mysql_` functions are deprecated. Second, running SQL queries with user input should always be done using parameterized commands.

Comment: would you like to give me example of parameterized commands from above post parameters..i used mysql_real_escape_string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out my mistake there is no issue of 'primary key' or 'Unique' constraint but problem with qutoes which i forget to add `` with database fields and second thing is that users give input 5'6 which make problem to insert in to database so i use mysql_real_escape_string to solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that there is no 'primary key' or 'Unique' constraint in the Profile table because if there is so then it will not allow duplicate values to be inserted. Also make sure that the variables have some value for the columns in which NULL insertion in MySQL is not allowed. (in Php MySQL by default NULL is not allowed)

Comment: But my question is still why 40 records inserted and 10 missing?

Comment: It is because the constraints did not allow all the entries to be inserted